# I can't find the implementation for Storage Facade in laravel

Tags: laravel, filesystems, storage

I'm new  with  laravel and I'm working in fileststem  on laravel
(I want to do usual fileststem process like -make dir - copy - put -delete -ect)

I'm using laravel "Storage" Facade 
but when i type

i referenced the class above like this in my code

```
 use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
```

for example below :

```
 if (file_exists(public_path($oldImage))) {
                Storage::delete($oldImage);
            }
```

nothing happens ,and when i refer to the class code i  found this :

```
namespace Illuminate\Support\Facades;

/**
 * @see \Illuminate\Filesystem\FilesystemManager
 */
class Storage extends Facade
{
    /**
     * Get the registered name of the component.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    protected static function getFacadeAccessor()
    {
        return 'filesystem';
    }
}
```

so where is the implementation and if you have alternative way to deal with 
filesystem process rather than "Storage" facade  ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Storage is a `facade` and accesses the class `Filesystem` located here: `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.php`

As you can see in the [official filesystem documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/master/filesystem) the code snippets use `Storage`.

**UPDATE:**

You should add `use Storage;` to be able to use the `Storage` facade.

Comment: i used  "Filesystem" in my constructor and it's works , but back to my original question why "Storage" facade class does not do the job in my case  ,,, why it's not pointing to the  "Filesystem"  class !!

Comment: Great that it works! You just asked where the implementation of `Storage` is  and it is in the file in my post ;)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend reading the Laravel 8.X docs to get an initial heads up: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/filesystem

**NOTE**: Before you get too carried away, make sure you understand the difference between `local` and `public`.

For starters, you should make your first goal to upload a file and acquire the `UploadedFile` type.

You can access a single file via something like `$request->file('name')`, or an array of images via something like:

```
// $request->input('images')

foreach ($images as $image) {
    \Log::debug($image->getClientOriginalName());
}
```

If your file upload can be single and/or multiple, I recommend going with the array approach because a single file wrapped in an array allows you to use the same syntax for single and multi uploads (ie: that foreach loop works fine with one image, no extra code).

Here's an example:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

$slug = 'davids-sandwich-photos';

foreach ($images as $image) {
    Storage::putFileAs(
        'images' .'/'. $slug,
        $image,
        $image->getClientOriginalName()
    );
}
```

`Storage::putFileAs()` can take 3 parameters: directory, content, filename. You can see above in the code that I interpolated a mix of static and derived directory name. You could do something like `'images' .'/'. $slug .'/'. Auth::user()->id` to save the file in `/images/davids-sandwich-photos/11`.

Then, check in your repo directory: `/storage/app/` and look for the `images` directory.

You can manually delete the folders while testing to get your bearings straight.

That should be enough to get most people started.

To avoid using the `Storage` facade, you can use:

```
 foreach ($images as $image) {
     $image->storeAs(
         'examples' .'/'. $slug,
         $image->getClientOriginalName(),
         'public'
     );
 }
```

--

Check out `config/filesystems.php` under the `disks` section if you want to start manipulating the drivers, but I'm not a DB admin expert here.

I also saved this along my journey: https://medium.com/@shafiya.ariff23/how-to-store-uploaded-images-in-public-folder-in-laravel-5-8-and-display-them-on-shared-hosting-e31c7f37a737. You might need that if you get stuck with something like symlinking.

```
            <img
                v-for="image in example.images"
                :key="image.filename"
                :src="`/storage/examples/${example.slug}/${image.filename}`"
            >
```

NOTE: The important part with Vue JS is to use `<img src="/storage/examples/slug/filename.jpg">` if your file is located in your repository as `/storage/app/public/examples/slug/filename.jpg` Pay close attention to every character.

Answer (score -1):

The public_path function returns the fully qualified path to the public directory ie public directory inside the laravel application. When using Storage, the path is set to the storage/app directory.

```
if (file_exists(public_path($oldImage))) {
  //public_path($oldImage) will check for file in public directory
  Storage::delete($oldImage); //Will delete file in storage/app directory
}
```

The modified code should be

```
if(Storage::has($oldImage)){
    Storage::delete($oldImage);
}
```